# Java Servlet response doesn't seem to finish

Tags: java, servlets

First of all, please have mercy for this noobie question. I’m currently working on a web application project and stumbled across this basic problem I can’t figure out to fix.

Basically, I have the following:

- index.html sending a POST request to servlet1.
- servlet1 sending a redirect to the browser to servlet2.
- servlet2 to return content.

I do see the content returned from servlet2 in my browser, but when I look into IE Developer Tools (F12), I see that the GET request to servlet2 never finishes (STATUS PENDING). There must be something very basic that I’m missing…

In below screen shot, "Ausstehend" translates to "pending".

IE Screenshot:
[image: IE F12 Screenshot]

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="servlet1" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="test" placeholder="some data">
            <button type="submit"><b>send</b></button>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

servlet1:

```
public class servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("servlet2");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

servlet2:

```
public class servlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet servlet2</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>HELLO</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried flushing `out`, with `out.flush()`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Just tried it but doesn't make a difference.

Comment: BTW: When I call servlet2 directly from the browser, the request finishes as expected.

Comment: ... and when sending a GET instead of a POST request to servlet1, things are ok too.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to explicitely set a status: `response.setStatus(SC_OK);`

Comment: Setting the Status Code also doesn't seem to make any difference. Please see also above comment. Why does it work when I send a GET to servlet1, but not when sending a POST to servlet1?

Comment: First thing I would do is try it with another browser, like chrome or firefox and see if you can reproduce the results. Could be an IE bug.

Comment: Wow... indeed. It seems to be an IE bug. It does work fine with Chrome and with Edge. I can't believe there are Bugs in IE for such fundamental cases.

Comment: What you could try is send code 303 (see other) instead of 302, which always should be followed up with GET, but I dont know if it makes any difference. For 302 they only say most browsers follow up with GET, but that doesnt seem to be the problem.

Comment: Would be done like this: `response.setStatus(response.SC_SEE_OTHER);
response.setHeader("Location",url);`, cannot use sendRedirect

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just tried it and the symptoms in IE remain the same. In Edge, Chrome and Firefox both options work (302 and 303).

Comment: @maraca - Actually, now I remember encountering this bug before when I was programming servlets, but that was a very long time ago. Good find!